# Merging multiple series in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have multiple data series in an array like this :

```
[
    {
        "key": "series1",
        "values": [
            {
                "x": 1378405800000, "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": 1378407600000, "y": 0
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "series2",
        "values": [
            {
                "x": 1378405800000, "y": 0
            },
            {
                "x": 1378407600000, "y": 0
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ..
]
```

I use the following to merge them :

```
var t = {};
var o = data2; //above data structure

for( srs = 0; srs < o.length; srs++ )
{
        key = o[srs]['key'];
        for ( ele = 0; ele < o[srs]['values'].length; ele++ )
        {
                mykey = o[srs]['values'][ele]['x'];
                if (!t.hasOwnProperty(mykey))
                t[mykey] = {};
                t[mykey]['x'] = o[srs]['values'][ele]['x'];
                t[mykey][key] = o[srs]['values'][ele]['y'];
        }
}

var multseries = [];
for (ele in t)
multseries.push(t[ele]);
```

Q1 Is this possible via d3.js API, using map or nest ?

Q2 Is there a better way to do this with or without d3.js? This will go through each element of all series once, but one series at a time. Is it possible to merge in order of x (fetch and merge elements x-wise). Also what if some elements are missing in a series.

Comment: Regarding your first question, I don't think that would be easier using D3's helper functions. There's nothing for merging data structures like this.

Comment: Found an example which is helpful to my situation - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685. The data used is almost like mine (can adapt to it easily).